# Putting list of image file into listbox in vb.net 2022

Tags: vb.net

i have 1 listbox with file names in it with this code

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder1Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder2Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder3Path.Text Then
            MsgBox("Unable to open a same folder")
        Else
            SourceFolderPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Dim filenames As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
            If filenames.Length > 0 Then
                For Each names As String In filenames
                    Dim justname As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(names)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(justname)
                Next
            End If
        End If
```

and it throw result like this :

```
456.pub
1.img
gmoier.img
```

how to make the listbox only list image files only. i've tried to add **`filenames.OfType(Of Image)`** after **`filenames.Length > 0`** but it ends with error.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with the `ListBox`. It's purely about getting the file paths. When you call `GetFiles`, you can provide a pattern to get only files that match that pattern, or provide no pattern and get all files. You can only provide one pattern though. If you want files that match multiple patterns, e.g. "*.jpg" and "*.png", then you need to call `GetFiles` multiple times and combine the results. Here's one example that does that, also using the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` types and data binding:

```vb
Dim fileTypes = {"*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif"}
Dim files As New List(Of FileInfo)
Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo("folder path here")

For Each fileType In fileTypes
    files.AddRange(folder.GetFiles(fileType))
Next

files.Sort(Function(fi1, fi2) fi1.Name.CompareTo(fi2.Name))

With ListBox1
    .DisplayMember = NameOf(FileInfo.Name)
    .ValueMember = NameOf(FileInfo.FullName)
    .DataSource = files
End With
```

Now, when the user selects a file by name from the list, you can get the full path from the `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: how do i remove and add something from the listbox when it's binded into the datasource,. I have no idea about how to move the data from one listbox to another listbox, I've tried deleting data from listbox1 with this code `ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)` and create same data to listbox2 which binded with another datasource with this code `ListFolder1.Items.Insert(0, ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)`, and it says i can't change listbox which binded with datasources.

Comment: @IrfanAzhari, you don't have to bind the data if you don't want to. The important point is that you need to call Get Files multiple times with different patterns and combine the results. That said, you should bind the data and, if you do, you need to manipulate the data source rather than the control. If you want to make changes then you should bind via a BindingSource. That's getting beyond the scope of this question though, so you should post a new question on that topic specifically if you need more help.

Comment: sure, i'll post a new question about moving the data between listbox, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended by using this code in any listbox in my form which didn't bind the listbox into datasources but still able to filter the image files.

```
Private Sub LoadISrcFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadISrcFolderToolStripMenuItem.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder1Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder2Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder3Path.Text Then
            MsgBox("Unable to open a same folder")
        Else
            SourceFolderPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

            'code for filtering the extension and adding item to listbox
            Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
            Dim extensionslist() As String = {"*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp", "*.tiff", "*.webp"}
            For Each extension As String In extensionslist
                For Each myFile As IO.FileInfo In Directory.GetFiles(extension)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(myFile)
                Next
            Next

        End If
```

and it works great, thanks for y'all suggestion and help :).